# How to sum to achieve total in sql

Tags: sql

I have a list of sales id followed by their total sales and buys. I want to now sum total sales and buys. I have attempted to insert sum totalbuy and totalsell as total. But this has not worked.

```
select sales_id, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'buy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalbuy, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'sell' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalsell 
from car_orders 
where sales_id like '%%' 
GROUP BY sales_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  sales_id, 
  totalbuy, 
  totalsell, 
  (totalbuy + totalsell) as total 
FROM
 (SELECT 
   sales_id, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'buy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalbuy, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'sell' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalsell
   FROM car_orders 
   WHERE sales_id like '%%' 
   GROUP BY sales_id)q
```

or if side can only be 'buy' or 'sell'

```
SELECT 
  sales_id, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'buy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalbuy, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'sell' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalsell,
  COUNT(*) as total
FROM car_orders 
WHERE sales_id like '%%' 
GROUP BY sales_id
```

Comment: thanks Raphael! It says I have to wait a few minutes before I can mark as answer.

Comment: Is there a way to limit sales_id to 10 people and then rank them according to totals, at present there are say 20 ids?

Comment: @userH yes, but solution is not the same in different dbms, so... your SQL tag is not sufficient ;)

Comment: well could you provide an example or a website I could look at for info?

Comment: I just realised I could possibly echo the table and use a table sorter (Jquery) to rank

Answer (score 0):

```
select sales_id, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'buy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalbuy, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'sell' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalsell,
   SUM(1) as totalbuyplussell 
from car_orders 
where sales_id like '%%' 
GROUP BY sales_id
```

Assuming side = buy OR sell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the total over all salesids that match the `where` clause, then drop the `group by`:

```
select 
   SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'buy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalbuy, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'sell' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalsell 
from car_orders 
where sales_id like '%%'
```